How to achieve efficient "bag of tasks" pattern in C multi-threading?
I am doing a costly computation that regards a combinatorial problem. The details of said problem are unimportant for this question, so I will omit them for now. The bulk of the time is spent on calculated values of a ComplicatedFunction(x) for x=2,...,x=N. Here, N varies, but for the time being it is typically 100-2000. The runtime of a single computation is roughly O((N-x)^3), decreasing with increasing x. Because these computations are long, but nearly independent (they read some shared data and write into the same aggregate variable, which is easily handled by a mutex), I thought that multi-threading is the perfect candidate for the next speed-up. Moreover, because the individual runs have vastly different runtimes, the "bad of tasks" pattern I learnt some time ago in a concurrency class sounded like the thing I wanted (although it has been a while since then).
The trouble is that I am very new to programming in C, which is what I am asking for help on. Also, I am currently doing this on a Windows machine, which brings in additional complications, as described later. So the thing to do may just be to move to a machine where I could use POSIX threads with #include <pthreads.h>.
What I have right now now is I create, for each x, a separate thread (likely mistake #1, spawning hundreds of threads like that) and make them compute the function values in their own time.
Secondly, multi-threading in Windows C does have its WaitForMultipleObjects() but it only supports stopping up to 64 threads, so to ensure all of the ComplicatedFunction(x) values are calculated before finishing the program run, I use a SynchronizationBarrier object. This barrier is accessed by the main thread and once a thread computing ComplicatedFunction(x) finishes, it too goes into the barrier. In an earlier version, each computing thread would instead spawn an additional thread which would "knock" on the barrier (another mistake, but with my limited knowledge, that is what I came up with at first). In the end, the barrier has enough threads entering it to let the main thread finish the run and terminate.
After all of this hassle, one of my smaller instances, which ran for ~2.5 minutes with the non-threaded version now runs in over 3 minutes.
I also tried an instance which previously took ~8.5 minutes just before posting and its multi-threaded version required only ~6.5 minutes. (with N large, it is very easy to have the sequential program take hours, even days, but this is the comparison I measured for the time being). That is at least faster, but not as big of a speed-up as I was hoping for with the threading. I assume I'm creating a lot of overhead within the program, because of my inefficient and inexperienced C coding. Alternatively, it could be that my laptop is refusing to give me (to give C, really) many threads for this, in which case, how do I make it cooperate better?
Lastly, a syntax question, are EnterSynchronizationBarrier(&barrier, SYNCHRONIZATION_BARRIER_FLAGS_BLOCK_ONLY); and EnterSynchronizationBarrier(&barrier, 0); equivalent?
Any and all helping pointers are appreciated!
Toy bare-bones implementation of the threads and barrier that I have currently going on.
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define THREAD_COUNT 700
int total_sum = 0;
HANDLE sum_mutex;
SYNCHRONIZATION_BARRIER barrier;

void ComplicatedFunction(int x) {
    printf("Received the parameter = %d\n", x);
    // Execute ComplicatedFunction's computations.
    WaitForSingleObject(sum_mutex, INFINITE);
    total_sum += x;
    ReleaseMutex(sum_mutex);
    EnterSynchronizationBarrier(&barrier, SYNCHRONIZATION_BARRIER_FLAGS_BLOCK_ONLY);
    return;
}

int main() {
    DWORD ids_of_computing_threads[THREAD_COUNT];
    HANDLE computing_threads[THREAD_COUNT];

    sum_mutex = CreateMutexW(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    InitializeSynchronizationBarrier(&barrier, THREAD_COUNT + 1, -1);

    for(int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++ ) {
        computing_threads[i] = CreateThread(
            NULL,                           // default security attributes
            0,                              // use default stack size
            ComplicatedFunction,            // thread function name
            i,                              // argument to thread function
            0,                              // use default creation flags
            &ids_of_computing_threads[i]);  // returns the thread identifier
    }
    // Wait until all threads have terminated:
    EnterSynchronizationBarrier(&barrier, SYNCHRONIZATION_BARRIER_FLAGS_BLOCK_ONLY);
    // And then close everything down:
    for(int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
        CloseHandle(computing_threads[i]);
    }
    CloseHandle(sum_mutex);
    DeleteSynchronizationBarrier(&barrier);
    printf("Final sum: %d\n", total_sum);
    return 0;
}


Instead of one thread per work item, which creates contention for processing and adds overhead for thread creation, create a small number of threads, say T. T might be about the number of processors available, possibly less depending on system load. To start (simpler to code), create T threads, and give each thread 1/T of the cases to work on. Timing that can give you an idea if this is on the right track. Then, for a more sophisticated solution, write a function for each thread that gets its next case from a queue. The main thread (or another you designate) would fill the queue.

@Pavol –
By the way, if you want to try POSIX threads, you could use the Ubuntu "app" (Linux Subsystem for Windows) on your machine.

I strongly advise you to give a look to OpenMP. This is the standard for multithreading in high-performance computing. In one line (eg. #pragma omp parallel for, you can create/recycle a pool of threads, share the work to the workers, and wait for the result. OpenMP is portable (as opposed to your Windows-specific code) and pretty optimized. It supports tasks with dependencies which is quite a pain to implement efficiently, especially for someone new in C. Critical sections can also be done in 1 line (#pragma omp critial). In the end, your program can be written in few lines in OpenMP.

In addition of the ones pointed out by EricPostpischil, a reduction is better than mutexes for total_sum, and you should avoid global variables like the plague in parallel code (they are a big source of bugs and performance issues). Here is an example of OpenMP code (you need to add the compilation flag -fopenmp with GCC/Clang and /openmp with MSVC).

Oh and do not forget to enable compiler optimisations flags which are not enabled by default ;) , that is -O3 for GCC/Clang, possibly -march=native for generating binaries specific to your CPU, and /O2 for MSVC.

If you read it right you want an answer for windows so please that tag.
